# How to fix sql create function error "Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS."?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create function in SQL Server 2008
with this query

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fJatah]
                    (@kodewil CHAR (30), @tgl CHAR (19))
                    RETURNS INT
                    AS
                    BEGIN
                    RETURN
                    (
                        SELECT a.AFDL, sum(Libur) as Libur, sum(Aktif) as Aktif
                        FROM (SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT a.AFDL, a.kd_wil, ISNULL(MAX(b.libur), 0) AS Libur, ISNULL(MAX(b.aktif), 0) AS Aktif
                        FROM dbo.vM_KEL AS a LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                                                    dbo.TblJatahSPTA AS b ON a.KD_KT = b.kd_kt LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                                                    dbo.tblSPA AS d ON a.KD_KT = LEFT(d.Kdptn, 5) AND d.tglberlaku = @tgl
                        WHERE a.AFDL = @kodewil
                        GROUP BY a.AFDL,a.KD_KT, a.kd_wil
                        ORDER BY a.AFDL) as a
                        GROUP BY a.AFDL
                    )
                    END
```

But i got error like this

> [Err] 42000 - [SQL Server]Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

I have no idea how to fix that, how can i fix my query?

Comment: So is it SQLServer or MySQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function is declared with `RETURNS INT`. That means, that you have to select exactly **one single value** (=scalar value) to return. In your case your `SELECT` specifies multiple return columns (`a.AFDL`, `Libur` and `Aktif`).

One thing you should know: *Scalar functions* (called *UDF*) are very bad performing. Much better in this case was an *inline table valued function* (called *iTVF*). Try it like this (not knowing what you are really doing here...):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fJatah]
                (@kodewil CHAR (30), @tgl CHAR (19))
                RETURNS TABLE
                AS
                RETURN
                    SELECT a.AFDL, sum(Libur) as Libur, sum(Aktif) as Aktif
                    FROM (SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT a.AFDL, a.kd_wil, ISNULL(MAX(b.libur), 0) AS Libur, ISNULL(MAX(b.aktif), 0) AS Aktif
                    FROM dbo.vM_KEL AS a LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                                                dbo.TblJatahSPTA AS b ON a.KD_KT = b.kd_kt LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                                                dbo.tblSPA AS d ON a.KD_KT = LEFT(d.Kdptn, 5) AND d.tglberlaku = @tgl
                    WHERE a.AFDL = @kodewil
                    GROUP BY a.AFDL,a.KD_KT, a.kd_wil
                    ORDER BY a.AFDL) as a
                    GROUP BY a.AFDL;
GO

SELECT * FROM [dbo].[fJatah]('SomeKodewil', 'SomeTgl')
GO
```

You can bind this `iTVF` into your commands with `CROSS APPLY` or use it where ever you might use a table (`FROM`, `JOIN` ...)